# Trigonometry question: $\sin^2(A) + \sin^2(B) - \sin^2(C) = 2\sin(A)\sin(B)\cos(C).$

Tags: trigonometry

Given $A + B + C = 180$, prove that $$\sin^2(A) + \sin^2(B) - \sin^2(C) = 2\sin(A)\sin(B)\cos(C).$$
I tried all identities I know but I have no idea how to proceed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

and $$\sin A=\sin[\pi-(B+C)]=\sin(B+C)$$

$$\sin^2A+\sin^2B-\sin^2C$$
$$=\sin^2 A+\sin(B-C)\sin(B+C)$$

$$=\sin A[\sin A+\sin(B-C)]$$

$$=\sin A[\sin(B+C)+\sin(B-C)]$$

$$=\sin A[2\sin B\cos C]$$
$$=2\sin A \sin B \cos C$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: @Kanishk, Please find the edited answer

Answer (score 5):

The given formula looks a lot like the law of cosines - and we can use this quite elegantly.

Note that we can interpret $A$, $B$, and $C$ as the angles in a triangle with side lengths $a$, $b$ and $c$. We can choose $a$ as anything we want, so let $a=\sin(A)$, and by the law of sines:

$$\frac{\sin (A)}{a}=\frac{\sin (B)}{b}=\frac{\sin (C)}{c}$$

we have a triangle with angles $A$, $B$, and $C$ such that $a=\sin (A)$, $b=\sin (B)$, and $c=\sin (C)$

Now we can apply the law of cosines:

$$
c^2=a^2+b^2-2ab\cos(C)
\implies \sin^2 (C)=\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-2\sin(A)\sin(B)\cos(C)
$$

Rearranging: voila, we get the desired equality!

$$\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-\sin^2 (C)=2\sin(A)\sin(B)\cos(C)$$