# In $\triangle ABC$, if $\sin^2{A}+\cos^2{C}=\cos^2{B}$,then $C=?$

Tags: trigonometry

In $\triangle ABC$, if $\sin^2{A}+\cos^2{C}=\cos^2{B}$,then  $C=?$

We have $\sin^2{A}+\cos^2{C}=\cos^2{B}  
\implies 2\sin^2{A}+2\cos^2{C}=2\cos^2{B}  
\implies 1-\cos{2A}+\cos{2C}-1=\cos{2B}-1  
\implies 1+\cos{2C}=\cos{2B}+\cos{2A}  
 \implies 1+\cos{2C}=2\cos(A+B)\cos(A-B)   
 \implies 1+\cos{2C}=2\cos(\pi-A)\cos(A-B)$, since $A+B+C=\pi$
 $\implies 1+\cos{2C}=2\cos{A}\cos(A-B)$

How can I find $C$ ? Please help.

Comment: Whenever you see such form of identity, my friend, the best optimization is that, identify this as a right-angle triangle. See, **C=pi/2** makes sense, as, it leaves **a= pi/2 + b** and so, **sin A = cos B**. There are many approaches you may like, but be sure to identify.

Comment: Pardon, there is a typo in my previous comment. I did not know that if five minutes elapse, I would be rendered unable to edit my own comment. (Just to confess my mistake.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$\sin^2A=\cos^2B-\cos^2C=\sin^2C-\sin^2B=\sin(C+B)\sin(C-B)$$

$$\implies\sin A\sin(\pi-\overline{B+C})=\sin(\pi-A)\sin(C-B)$$

$$\implies\sin A[\sin(B+C)-\sin(C-B)]=0$$

$$\implies\sin A[2\sin B\cos C]=0$$

$$\implies C = \frac\pi 2$$(as $ A,B,C\ne 0 $)

---

Alternatively, $$\cos^2C=\cos^2B-\sin^2A=\cos(B+A)\cos(B-A)$$

Again, $\cos(A+B)=\cos(\pi-C)=-\cos C$

$$\implies\cos C[-\cos(A+B)]=-\cos C\cos(B-A)\iff\cos C[\cos(B-A)-\cos(B+A)]=0$$

$$\iff\cos C[2\sin B\sin A]=0$$

$$\implies C = \frac\pi 2$$(as $ A,B,C\ne 0 $)