# Proving $\sin 20^\circ \, \sin 40^\circ \, \sin 60^\circ \, \sin 80^\circ =\frac{3}{16}$

Tags: trigonometry

The problem is to prove that

$$\sin 20^\circ \, \sin 40^\circ \, \sin 60^\circ \, \sin 80^\circ =\frac{3}{16}$$

All my attempts were to get them in $\sin (2A)$ form after eliminating $\sin 60^\circ$ in both sides. Unfortunately, all these attempts were futile.

Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: hint: $80=60+20$, $40=60-20$, $60=20+20+20$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Denote $Q = \sin 20 \sin 40 \sin 60 \sin 80$.  Observe first that

\begin{align}
\sin 60 & = \sin (20+40) \\
        & = \sin 20 \cos 40 + \cos 20 \sin 40 \\
        & = \sin 20 (2\cos^2 20 - 1) + \cos 20 (2 \sin 20 \cos 20) \\
        & = (4\cos^2 20 - 1) \sin 20
\end{align}

We can now write

\begin{align}
Q & = \sin 20 \sin (60-20) \sin 60 \sin (60+20) \\
  & = \sin 20 (\sin 60 \cos 20 - \cos 60 \sin 20)
      \sin 60 (\sin 60 \cos 20 + \cos 60 \sin 20) \\
  & = \sin 20 \sin 60 (\sin^2 60 \cos^2 20 - \cos^2 60 \sin^2 20) \\
  & = \sin 20 \sin 60 \frac{3\cos^2 20 - \sin^2 20}{4} \\
  & = \sin 20 \sin 60 \frac{4\cos^2 20 - 1}{4} \\
  & = \sin 60 \frac{(4\cos^2 20 - 1)\sin 20}{4} \\
  & = \sin 60 \frac{\sin 60}{4} \\
  & = \frac{\sin^2 60}{4} = \frac{3}{16}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

Using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$\sin(60^\circ-x)\cdot\sin x\sin(60^\circ+x)=\sin x[\sin^2120^\circ-\sin^2x]=\dfrac{3\sin x-4\sin^3x}4$$

$$\implies4\sin(60^\circ-x)\cdot\sin x\sin(60^\circ+x)=\sin3x$$

Set $x=20^\circ$

Comment: there should be $60^{\circ}$ instead of $120^{\circ}$?

Comment: @mnulb, $$\sin(180^\circ-x)=\sin x$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use  the so-called [Morrie's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morrie%27s_law) :

$\cos(20°)\cos(40°)\cos(80°)=1/8$

and

$\sin(20°)\sin(40°)\sin(80°)=\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{8}$.

Comment: Please consider using (10^{\circ}) to get $(10^{\circ})$ instead of (10°) which, in LaTeX gives the rather oddly spaced $(10°)$. Although, a constant use of the degree sign is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We have:

$\sin20^{\circ} = \sin(30^\circ - 10^\circ)= \frac{1}{2}\cos10^\circ - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin10^\circ$

$\sin40^{\circ} = \sin(30^\circ + 10^\circ)= \frac{1}{2}\cos10^\circ + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\sin10^\circ$

$\sin 60^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$

$\sin80^\circ =\cos 10^\circ$

Therefore,

$A = \sin20^\circ \sin40^\circ \sin60^\circ \sin80^\circ = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \left((\cos10^\circ )^2 - \frac{3}{4} \right)\cos10^\circ$

Moreover :

$ \cos30^\circ = 4(\cos10^\circ )^3 - 3\cos 10^\circ$, from this [cubic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function) we find out the value of $cos10^\circ$, and then plug it to the expression of $A$ we will get the answer.

Comment: Please consider using \sin and \cos to get $\sin$ and $\cos$ instead of $sin$ and $cos$. Also, consider using 10^{\circ} to get $10^{\circ}$ instead of $10^o$. (Although, reference to degrees is not really needed)

Comment: @Fly by Night Thank you!