# I've found two positive answers to $8cos(2x)=5$ where (x = 0.4478) and (x = 3.5894). How can I find a third solution? Details inside.

Tags: trigonometry

I added $pi + 0.4478$ which is the lowest positive answer I got from solving the expression and got 3.5894 as the second lowest positive answer. My web assignment marked both 0.4478 and 3.5894 as *correct*. I added $pi+3.5894$ thinking it would give me my third and final answer, but my web assignment marked it wrong. Is 6.7310 not the third smallest answer? Maybe there is another solution I m failing to find? Troubleshooting help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: As Michael Medvinsky's answer indicates, you have $0.4478$ and $\pi+0.4478$ (approx), but the third one would be $\pi-0.4478$ (approx), since cosine is an even function (so that $\cos x = \cos -x$).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Very helpful!

Comment: Also, Michael's answer needs a small edit (see below).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

Answer (score 1):

The answer is $$\pm\frac{1}{2} \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{5}{8}\right) +\pi n$$
where $n$ is an integer.

Comment: That should be $\pi n$, not $2\pi n$, since the argument of $\cos$ is $2x$, not $x$.