# period of the function $y = \sin^2\frac{\sqrt2x+3}{6\pi}$

Tags: periodic-functions

Today I came across a question

> The fundamental period of the function $y = \sin^2\frac{\sqrt2x+3}{6\pi}$ is $\lambda \pi^2$ then the value of $\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt2}$ is ___

I tried to equate the angle to $\pi$. Then I got $x=\frac{6\pi^2-3}{\sqrt2}$, which is not in the form of $\lambda\pi^2$. So even on further simplifying I am not getting the correct answer, which is 3. How to solve it?

Comment: Equating the angle to $\pi$ doesn't work when there is a constant inside the parentheses.

Comment: @MattSamuel ohhh...then what is the way?

Comment: Throw out the 3 in the numerator, then set equal to $\pi$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Yes...this is working...thanks..can you give me a reference for how this works?

Comment: The 3 is a phase shift, it doesn't affect the period. I would think this would be in your textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

As $\cos2A=1-2\sin^2A$

the required period will be that of $$\cos\dfrac{\sqrt2x+3}{3\pi}=f(x)$$

Now for $f(x+T)=f(x),$

using [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html)

we need $\sin\dfrac{\sqrt2T}{6\pi}=0\iff\dfrac{\sqrt2T}{6\pi}=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

Comment: The same can also be reached by using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b