# Prove $\sin(A-B)/\sin(A+B)=(a^2-b^2)/c^2$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

prove

For any triangle $\triangle ABC$, prove that

$$\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2}$$

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I'm confused where to start

Answer (score 5):

HINT:

Use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

and $\sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=?$

and [Sine Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin(A+B)}=\frac{\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A}{\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A} = \frac{2ac\cos B-2bc\cos A}{2ac\cos B+2bc\cos A}=\frac{(a^2-b^2+c^2)-(-a^2+b^2+c^2)}{(a^2-b^2+c^2)+(-a^2+b^2+c^2)}=\frac{a^2-b^2}{c^2}.$$