# A problem in Trigonometry (Properties of Triangles) v4

Tags: trigonometry

I need help with this sum:

> If $$\dfrac {\sin {A}}{\sin {B}} = \dfrac {\sin {(A-B)}}{\sin {(B-C)}} $$ prove that $a^2$, $b^2$ and $c^2$ are in A. P.

In my attempts, I tried to apply componendo and dividendo on both sides and then applied transformation rules for converting sums of sines to their products, and tried to get to something, but it was a failure.

Comment: HINT: $$A=\pi-(B+C)$$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b  and https://brilliant.org/wiki/sine-rule/

Comment: I believe you want $\frac{\sin A}{\sin C}$ on the left-hand side. (That is $\sin C$ instead of $\sin B$ in the denominator.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: using the Theorem of sines we get
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\sin(A)\cos(B)-\cos(A)\sin(B)}{\sin(B)\cos(C)-\cos(B)\sin(C)}$$
now set
$$\sin(A)=\frac{a}{b}\sin(B)$$ and
$$\sin(C)=\frac{c}{b}\sin(B)$$ and cancelling   $$\sin(B)\ne 0$$
we get
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{a\cos(B)-b\cos(A)}{b\cos(C)-c\cos(B)}$$
plugin the Theorem of cosines and simplifying we have
$$\frac{a}{b}=\frac{\frac{a^2-b^2}{c}}{\frac{b^2-c^2}{a}}$$
can you proceed?

Comment: That's enough, I got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment ,

as $A=\pi-(B+C),\sin A=\sin(B+C)$

Using  [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$P=\sin A\sin(B-C)=\sin(B+C)\sin(B-C)=\sin^2B-\sin^2C$$

Using [Law of Sines](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LawofSines.html),$$P=\dfrac{b^2-c^2}{(2R)^2}$$

So $\dfrac {\sin {A}}{\sin C} = \dfrac {\sin {(A-B)}}{\sin {(B-C)}}\implies\dfrac{b^2-c^2}{(2R)^2}=\dfrac{a^2-b^2}{(2R)^2} $