# Find $\frac{\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)}{\sin A\cos A-\sin B\cos B}$

Tags: trigonometry

> Find:$$\dfrac{\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)}{\sin A\cos A-\sin B\cos B}$$

I couldn't simplify afterwards so help me out

Comment: Is $a$ different from $A$? Is $b$ different from $B$.  Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Everything is in capital letters

Comment: Please share your thoughts so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original problem was $$\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\sin{a}\cos{a}-\sin{b}\cos{b}},$$
which is
$$\frac{\frac{1-\cos2a}{2}-\frac{1-\cos2b}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}\sin2a-\frac{1}{2}\sin2b}$$ or
$$\frac{\cos2b-\cos2a}{\sin2a-\sin2b}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin(a-b)\sin(a+b)}{\sin(a-b)\cos(a+b)}$$ or
$$\tan(a+b)$$

Comment: Is that a direct formula or based on numerator and denominator or are there some to that?

Comment: @user466377 I solved you previous problem: $\frac{\sin^2a-\sin^2b}{\sin{a}\cos{a}-\sin{b}\cos{b}}$

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

then $$2\sin A\cos A=\sin2A$$

finally  [Prosthaphaeresis](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas $$\sin C-\sin D=?$$