# Solving Trigonometric Functions: $4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi) =3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Find the sum of the three smallest positive values of $\theta$ such that $4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi) =3$. (Give your answer in radians.)

I have no idea on how to do this problem! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

\begin{align*}
\cos(2\theta - \pi) = \pm\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} = \pm\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Use double angle formula

$\cos(x-2\pi)=\cos x$

Alternatively, we can prove $\cos^2y=\cos^2B\implies y=m\pi\pm B$

Where $m$ is any integer

Comment: See also:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b

Answer (score 1):

Using method of difference of squares,
$$a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$$

$$4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi)=3$$
$$4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi)-3=0$$
$$(2\cos(2\theta-\pi)+\sqrt3)(2\cos(2\theta-\pi)-\sqrt3)=0$$

We then have two different solution.

$$\cos(2\theta-\pi)=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

$$\cos(2\theta-\pi)=-\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi)=3 \iff 2[\cos (4\theta-2\pi)+1]=3$$

$$\cos (4\theta-2\pi)+1=\frac{3}{2} \iff \cos (4\theta-2\pi)=\frac{1}{2}$$

$$\theta_1=\frac{\pi}{3}$$

$$4\theta-2\pi=\frac{\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi \iff 4\theta=\frac{7\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi$$

$$4\theta=\frac{7\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi \iff \theta=\frac{7\pi}{12}+\frac{\text n\pi}{2}$$

$$\theta_2=2\pi-\frac{\pi}{3}=\frac{5\pi}{3}$$

$$4\theta-2\pi=\frac{5\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi \iff 4\theta=\frac{11\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi$$

$$ 4\theta=\frac{11\pi}{3}+2\text n\pi \iff \theta=\frac{11\pi}{12}+\frac{\text n\pi}{2}$$

where $$ n=0,\pm1,\pm2,...$$

Answer (score 0):

Using $\cos2x = 2\cos^2x-1$, we get
$$4\cos^2(2\theta-\pi) = 2[\cos (4\theta-2\pi)+1]= 2\cos 4\theta + 2 = 3$$
Therefore,
$$ \cos 4\theta = \frac{1}{2} $$
$$ 4\theta = \pm \left(\frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi\right)$$
$$ \theta = \pm\left(\frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{n\pi}{2}\right)$$

It can also be expressed as 
$$ \theta = \pm \frac{\pi}{12} + \frac{n\pi}{2}$$