# Find the general solution of $3\csc^2 x - 4=0$.

Tags: trigonometry

Find the general solution of $3\csc^2 x - 4 =0$.

My Attempt:

$$3\csc^2 x - 4=0$$
$$\csc^2 x =\dfrac {4}{3}$$
$$\csc x = \pm \dfrac {2}{\sqrt {3}}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\csc x=\pm\frac2{\sqrt3}$, then $\sin x=\pm\frac{\sqrt3}2$, and so $x=\pm\frac{\pi}3+2k\pi$ or $x=\pm\frac{2\pi}3+2k\pi$, for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\csc^2 x = \frac 43$, then $\cot^2 x = \frac 13$, then $\tan x = \pm\sqrt3$, and so $x = \pm \frac\pi3 + k\pi$, for some $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: $\tan x$, not $\tan^2x$.

Comment: @zipirovich Done, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can prove  $$\sin^2x=\sin^2A\iff\cos^2x=\cos^2A\iff\tan^2x=\tan^2A$$ etc.

Now using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$\sin^2x=\sin^2A\iff\sin(x-A)\cdot\sin(x+A)=0\implies x=n\pi\pm A$$ where $n$ is any integer

Here $\csc^2x=\dfrac43\iff\sin^2x=\dfrac34=\sin^2\dfrac\pi3$