# An equation relating sine of angles in a triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I wanted to solve the following problem.

> In $\triangle ABC$ we have $$\sin^2 A + \sin^2 B = \sin^2 C + \sin A \sin B \sin C.$$ Compute $\sin C$.

Since it's an equation for a triangle, I assumed that $\pi = A + B + C$ would be important to consider.

I've tried solving for $\sin C$ as a quadratic, rewriting $\sin C = \sin (\pi - A - B)$, but nothing seemed to work.

How does one approach this problem? Any help would be appreciated.

The answer is

> $$\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{5}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the law of sines the triangle $ABC$ is a similar to the triangle with sides-lengths $\sin{A}$, $\sin{B}$ and $\sin{C}$.

Thus, by the law of cosines 
$$\sin^2C=\sin^2A+\sin^2B-2\sin{A}\sin{B}\cos{C}$$ and by the given
$$\sin^2C=\sin^2A+\sin^2B-\sin{A}\sin{B}\sin{C}.$$
Id est, $$2\cos{C}=\sin{C}$$ or
$$4(1-\sin^2C)=\sin^2C$$ or
$$\sin{C}=\frac{2}{\sqrt5}$$ or
$$C=\arcsin\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}}.$$
Done!

Comment: why squaring? it is the same like $$\tan(C)=2$$

Comment: Sonnhard We need to find $\sin{C}$.

Comment: when we find $C$ then also $$\sin(C)$$

Comment: are you sure that by squaring Comes no additioninal solution?

Comment: Sonnhard  Yes, of course! Because $\sin>0$ for all triangle.

Answer (score 1):

using the Theorem of sines we get
$$\sin^2(C)\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{c^2}\right)=\sin^2(C)+\frac{ab}{c^2}\sin^3(C)$$
since $$\sin(C)\neq 0$$ we obtain
$$\sin(C)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{ab}$$ using $$2\cos(C)=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{ab}$$ we get $$\tan(C)=2$$

Answer (score 0):

Using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

$$\sin^2A+\sin(B-C)\sin(B+C)=\sin A\sin B\sin C$$

As $\sin(B+C)=\sin(\pi-A)=\sin A$ and $\sin A>0$ cancelling it in both sides

$$\sin A+\sin(B-C)=\sin B\sin C$$

$$\sin(B+C)+\sin(B-C)=\sin B\sin C$$

$$\iff2\sin B\cos C=\sin B\sin C$$

As $\sin B>0,$  $$\dfrac{\sin C}2=\dfrac{\cos C}1=\pm\sqrt{\dfrac{\sin^2C+\cos^2C}{2^2+1^2}}=?$$

But again $\sin C>0$