# Further simplifying a trigonometric expression.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

How do I prove that $\dfrac{\sin(\alpha- \beta)}{\sin \alpha - \sin \beta}= \dfrac{\sin\alpha +\sin \beta}{\sin (\alpha + \beta)}$?

Using double angle and addition formulas, I simplified the LHS to  $\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{\alpha - \beta}{2}}{\cos\dfrac{\alpha +\beta}{2}}$

Comment: I would suggest clearing denominators and proving what you are left with.

Comment: Do the same for the RHS and you will complete the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method**$\#1:$

Use [Prosthaphaeresis Formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) and double angle formula: $$\sin2x=2\sin x\cos x$$ in the Right Hand Side as well.

**Method**$\#2:$

Alternatively using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b) , $$\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B=?$$

Comment: I got the simplified answer using Prosthaphaeresis formula.

Comment: @Abcd, Nice to hear that.But I think the problem came into being by method $\#2$

Answer (score 1):

$\dfrac{\sin(\alpha - \beta )}{\sin\alpha - \sin\beta}= \dfrac{\sin(\alpha - \beta )\sin (\alpha +\beta)}{(\sin\alpha - \sin\beta)(\sin (\alpha +\beta))}$

Recall that $\sin(\alpha - \beta)\sin(\alpha + \beta)= \sin^2 \alpha - \sin^2\beta$.

Simplifying, we get:

$\dfrac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\sin(\alpha +\beta)} =RHS$

Q.E.D.