# Prove that $\sin^2(a+b) = \sin^2a + \sin^2b + 2\sin a\sin b\cos(a+b)$

Tags: trigonometry

I tried starting with the left part of the equation which did not lead anywhere near the second

Comment: Use $e^{ix}=$cos$(x)+i$sin$(x)$

Comment: Use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Here are the steps
$$\begin{align}\sin^2(a+b)&=(\sin a\cos b+\sin b\cos a)^2\\&=\sin^2a\cos^2b+\sin^2b\cos^2a+2\sin a\cos b\sin b\cos a\\&=\sin^2a(1-\sin^2b)+\sin^2b(1-\sin^2a)+2\sin a\cos b\sin b\cos a\\&=\sin^2a+\sin^2b+2(\sin a\cos b\sin b\cos a-\sin^2a\sin^2b)\end{align}$$
Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the formulas for $\sin(a+b)$ and $\cos(a+b)$:

\begin{align}
\sin^2(a+b) &= \sin^2 a \cos^2 b + \cos^2 a \sin^2 b + 2\sin a \sin b \cos a \cos b \\
  &= \sin^2 a (1-\sin^2b)+(1-\sin^2a)\sin^2b + 2\sin a \sin b \cos a \cos b\\
  &= \sin^2a +\sin^2b + 2\sin a\sin b(\cos a\cos b-\sin a\sin b)
\\
&=\sin^2a +\sin^2b+2\sin a\sin b \cos(a+b)
\end{align}

Comment: Wow! 10 seconds before me :P

Comment: @ThePirateBay - Sorry, I am pretty slow...