# Trig Identity Verification

Tags: trigonometry

$$\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)=0$$

Using trig identity, we can write it equal to

$\cos(2t) = 0$
  where I get $2t = \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{3\pi}{2}$
which means $t = \frac{\pi}{4}, \ \frac{3\pi}{4}$

or (without trig identity)

$$\cos^2(t)=\sin^2(t)$$
where I get $t = \frac{\pi}{4},\ \frac{3\pi}{4}, \ \frac{5\pi}{4},\ \frac{7\pi}{4}$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not true that $\cos(2t)=0\implies 2t=\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$.

Comment: In your first approach these are all of the solutions inside the interval $t\in[0,\pi]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos(2t) = 0$ implies that $2t = \pi(n+1/2) $ where $n= 0, \pm 1, \pm 2, ... $ since $\cos(\pi(n+1/2)) = 0$ for those values of $n$. You're simply missing a few of these solutions above. In the same way your neglecting other solutions when you solve without trig identity. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

**Method**$\#1:$
$$2t=(2m+1)\dfrac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer

**Method**$\#2:$

$$\cos^2t=\sin^2t\implies\sin^2t=1-\sin^2t$$

$$\iff\sin^2t=\dfrac12=\sin^2\dfrac\pi4$$

Now use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b),

If $\sin\left(t-\dfrac\pi4\right)=0, t-\dfrac\pi4=n\pi$ where $n$ is any integer

What if  $\sin\left(t+\dfrac\pi4\right)=0?$

More generally, if $$\sin^2x=\sin^2A\iff\cos^2x=\cos^2A\iff\tan^2x=\tan^2A$$

Can you prove $x=r\pi\pm A$ where $r$ is any integer

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution:

$$\cos^2(t)-\sin^2(t)=0$$

$$\sin^2(t)=\cos^2(t)$$

$$\tan^2(t)=1$$

$$\tan(t)= \pm 1$$

thus $$t= \frac{π}4,\frac{3π}4,\frac{5π}4,\frac{7π}4$$

**NOTE:**

keep attention when from here
$$\sin^2(t)=\cos^2(t)$$ 
dividing by $\cos^2(t)$ and obtain
$$\tan^2(t)=1$$ 
you are assuming that $\cos^2(t) \neq0$ that's a correct assumption here because $t=\pm\frac{π}2$ do not satisfy the original equation.