# Proving $\sin^2x \cos^2y - \cos^2x \sin^2y \;\equiv\; \cos^2y - \cos^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

Knowing

$$\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta \equiv 1$$

how would I prove:
$$\sin^2x \cos^2y - \cos^2x \sin^2y \;\equiv\; \cos^2y - \cos^2x$$

Can I substitute the first equation to prove the second one? If so, how can I?

Please help.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: The right-hand side of the target relation has only cosines in it. Can you use the Pythagorean identity to get rid of the sines on the left-hand side?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the right hand side only has cosines in it. Try replacing all of the $\sin^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(y)$ with $1-\cos^2(x)$ and $1-\cos^2(y)$ respectively. If you simplify, you will see the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** you can substitute the first equation into the second one.

$\sin^2\theta +\cos^2\theta \equiv 1 \implies \sin^2\theta = 1-\cos^2\theta$

Substitute to get,

$\begin{eqnarray}
\sin^2x \cos^2y - \cos^2x \sin^2y &=& ((1-\cos^2(x)) (\cos^2y)) - ((\cos^2x) (1-\cos^2(y)) \\\\ 
&=& \cos^2y - ((\cos^2y)(\cos^2x)) - \cos^2x + ((\cos^2x)(\cos^2y)) \\\\ 
&=& \cos^2y - \cos^2x
\end{eqnarray}$

Answer (score 0):

$\sin^2x \cos^2y - \cos^2x \sin^2y \\
= \sin^2x \cos^2y + (\cos^2x \cos^2y - \cos^2x \cos^2y) - \cos^2x \sin^2y \\
= (\sin^2x + \cos^2x) \cos^2y - \cos^2x (\cos^2y + \sin^2y) \\
= \cos^2y - \cos^2x$