# In triangle ABC, find the value of $\sum a^2(\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)$

Tags: trigonometry, triangles

The expression is 
$$a^2(\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)+b^2(\cos^2 C-\cos^2 A)+c^2(\cos^2 A-\cos^2B)$$
$$=a^2\sin A\sin (C-B)+b^2\sin B \sin (A-C) + c^2\sin C \sin (B-A)$$
$$=k\sin^3A\sin (C-B)+k\sin^3B\sin (A-C) + k\sin ^3 C\sin (B-A)$$
I couldn’t solve further, the answer is an integer value. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note,

$$I = a^2(\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)+b^2(\cos^2 C-\cos^2 A)+c^2(\cos^2 A-\cos^2B)$$

$$=4R^2 \left[ \sin^2 A (\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)+\sin^2 B (\cos^2 C-\cos^2 A)+\sin^2 C (\cos^2 A-\cos^2B)\right]$$

where $R$ is the circumradius. Then, use the identities $\cos^2x = \frac12(1+\cos2x)$ and $\sin^2x= \frac12(1-\cos2x)$ to reexpress $I$ as,

$$\frac I{R^2} = (1-\cos2A)(\cos2B-\cos2C)+ (1-\cos2B)(\cos2C-\cos2A)+  (1-\cos2C)(\cos2A-\cos2B)=0$$

Edit:

$$I = a^2(\sin^2 C-\sin^2 B)+b^2(\sin^2 A-\sin^2 C)+c^2(\sin^2 B-\sin^2A)= \frac{ a^2(c^2-b^2)+b^2(a^2-c^2)+c^2(b^2-a^2)}{4R^2}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

For $\triangle ABC$ we have a rule known as projection rule which states that

$a=b\ cosC+c\ cosB$

$b=c\ cosA+a\ cosC$

$c=b\ cosA+a\ cosB$

The given expression can be re-arranged to be written as

$a^2\cos^2B-b^2\cosÂ+b^2\cos^2C-c^2\cos^2B+c^2\cos^2A-a^2\cos^2C$

$=(a\cos B+b\cos A)(a\cos B-b\cos A)+(b\cos C+c\cos B)(b\cos C-c\cos B)+(c\cos A+a\cos C)(c\cos A-a\cos C)$

$=c(a\cos B-b\cos A)+a(b\cos C-c\cos B)+b(c\cos A-a\cos C)$

$=0$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\cos^2B-\cos^2C=1-\sin^2B-(1-\sin^2C)=?$$

Now replace $a$ with $2R\sin A$

Comment: @user600016, I  have suggested $$a^2(\cos^2B-\cos^2C)=\cdots=4R^2(\sin^2C\sin^2A-\sin^2A\sin^2B)$$

Comment: Oh sorry my bad

Comment: Isn’t that essentially what I did, unless you don’t mean to use the sin(A-B)sin(A+B) formula

Comment: @Aditya, Have you noticed the cyclic form I've arrived at. You will be entangled if you use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b

Comment: @Aditya, if we write $\sin^2A=p$ etc, we shall get $$4R^2(pq-qr+qr-rp+rp-pq)=?$$

Answer (score 0):

Using
\begin{align} 
\cos A&=\frac{-a^2+b^2+c^2}{2bc}
,\\
\cos B&=\frac{a^2-b^2+c^2}{2ac}
,\\
\cos C&=\frac{a^2+b^2-c^2}{2ab}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align}
a^2(\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)+b^2(\cos^2 C-\cos^2 A)+c^2(\cos^2 A-\cos^2B)
&=0
.
\end{align}

Comment: Did you square cosA? Seems a bit too long, no?

Comment: @Aditya: The result would not be zero otherwise.

Comment: I don't think squaring would be expected. There is bound to be a shorter version

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Let $h_a,h_b,h_c$ be the altitudes in corresponding $\triangle ABC$.
Consider
\begin{align} 
u&=a^2-h_b^2+b^2-h_c^2+c^2-h_a^2
\\
&=
a^2\cos^2 C+b^2\cos^2 A+c^2\cos^2 B
,\\
v&=a^2-h_c^2+b^2-h_a^2+c^2-h_b^2
\\
&=
a^2\cos^2 B+b^2\cos^2 C+c^2\cos^2 A
\end{align}

\begin{align}
0&=v-u
=
a^2(\cos^2 B-\cos^2 C)+b^2(\cos^2 C-\cos^2 A)+c^2(\cos^2 A-\cos^2B)
.
\end{align}

This also holds for obtuse triangles:

[image]