# Given that $\alpha + \beta - \gamma = \pi$, prove that $\sin^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \beta - \sin^2 \gamma = 2 \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma$.

Tags: trigonometry

I am told:

$$\alpha + \beta - \gamma = \pi$$

And I have to prove:

$$\sin^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \beta - \sin^2 \gamma = 2 \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma$$

What should I be looking for? I kept trying to take the sine of bots sides and use the formulas:

$$\sin(a + b) = \sin a \cos b + \sin b \cos a$$

$$\sin(a-b) = \sin a \cos b - \sin b \cos a$$

but got nowhere. Then I tried using the formulas:

$$\sin a + \sin b = 2 \sin \bigg ( \dfrac{a + b}{2} \bigg ) \cos\bigg ( \dfrac{a - b}{2} \bigg )$$

$$\sin a - \sin b = 2 \cos \bigg ( \dfrac{a + b}{2} \bigg ) \sin \bigg ( \dfrac{a - b}{2} \bigg )$$

But again, I got nowhere. Can you give me a hint? At least what should I be looking for? What should be my strategy? Everything that I did felt just random, while kind of hoping that everything would just magically turn into the desired result. What is the strategy for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say that: $\sin(\alpha+\beta)=\sin(\pi +\gamma)$.  Now, I can evaluate the expression: $$\sin(\alpha)^2+\sin(\beta)^2-\sin(\gamma)^2=\sin(\alpha)^2+\sin(\beta)^2-\sin(\alpha)^2\cos(\beta)^2-\sin(\beta)^2\cos(\alpha)^2-\sin(\alpha)\cos(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\beta)$$

Now substitute $\cos(\alpha)^2$ and $\cos(\beta)^2$, and obtain: $$2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)(\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)-cos(\alpha)\cos(\beta))=2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)(-1\cdot\cos(\alpha+\beta))=2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)$$

Also: $$\cos(\gamma)=\cos(\alpha+\beta-\pi)=\cos(\pi-(\alpha+\beta))=-\cos(\alpha+\beta)$$

From here, as you wanted: $$\sin(\alpha)^2+\sin(\beta)^2-\sin(\gamma)^2=2\sin(\alpha)\sin(\beta)\cos(\gamma)$$

Comment: But isn't it that $\cos(a + b) = \cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b$? So shouldn't we have in your second to last line $\sin(\alpha) \sin(\beta) - \cos(\alpha) \cos(\beta) = - \cos(\alpha + \beta)$ instead of $\cos(\alpha + \beta)$?

Comment: @user1502: see my edits.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

$$\sin^2\beta-\sin^2\gamma=\sin(\beta+\gamma)\sin(\beta-\gamma)=\sin(\beta+\gamma)\sin(\pi-\alpha)=\sin(\beta+\gamma)\sin\alpha$$

Again,$$\sin^2\alpha=\sin\alpha\cdot\sin(\beta-\gamma)$$

Hope you can take it home from here?

Answer (score 1):

$$\sin^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \beta - \sin^2 \gamma-2 \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma=$$

$$=\sin^2 \alpha + \sin^2 \beta -1+\cos^2(\alpha+\beta)+2 \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos (\alpha+\beta)=$$
$$=\sin^2 \alpha-\cos^2 \beta+\cos(\alpha+\beta)\cos(\alpha-\beta)=$$
$$=\sin^2 \alpha-\cos^2 \beta+\cos^2\alpha\cos^2\beta-\sin^2\alpha\sin^2\beta=$$
$$=(1-\sin^2\beta)\sin^2\alpha-(1-\cos^2\alpha)\cos^2\beta=0.$$