# factor $\sin ^2x-\cos ^22x+\cos ^23x-\sin ^24x$

Tags: trigonometry

Factor 
$$\sin ^2x-\cos ^22x+\cos ^23x-\sin ^24x$$

---

I got $$\frac{1}{2}\left(\cos 6x+\cos 8x-\cos 2x-\cos 4x\right)$$
but i don't know how to continue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As

$$6+4=8+2$$ use [Prosthaphaeresis](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html) Formulas  on $$\cos6x-\cos4x\text{  and on   
  }\   \   \cos8x-\cos2x$$

Alternatively as $x+4x=2x+3x$

use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

$$\sin^2x-\sin^24x=-\sin(4x-x)\sin(4x+x)$$

and $$\cos^22x-\cos^23x=1-\sin^22x-(1-\sin^23x)=\sin(3x+2x)\sin(3x-2x)$$