# Computing a certain trigonometric determinant

Tags: trigonometry, determinant, triangles

[image]

Friends please help me out to solve this question

Comment: For elementary/homework/computation questions of this form, we generally ask that you show any progress you've made and you point out *specifically* where you are stuck. We want to help you understand the problem; we don't want to do your homework for you.

Comment: Try with $A=\pi/2$ and $B=C=\pi/4$.

Comment: It is not my homework and I tried this question by applying row coloumn method but after applying row coloumn method I am getting a equation which I am not able to solve there I stuck.

Comment: @egreg Is this the right method to put values and solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint

Start with $R_2'=R_2-R_1, R_3'=R_3-R_1$

$$\cot B-\cot A=\dfrac{\sin(A-B)}{\sin A\sin B}$$

Using [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b)

$$\sin^2B-\sin^2A=-\sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)$$

Finally $A+B=\pi-C$