# Find the general value of $\theta$ for the inverse trigonometric function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$\text { Find the general value of } \theta, \text { when } 9 \sec ^{4} \theta=16$

My work-

Given $\sec ^{4} \theta=\frac{16}{9}$
or, $\sec ^{4} \theta = \frac{(4)^{2}}{(3)^{2}}$

$\implies \sec ^{2} \theta=\frac{4}{3} \Longrightarrow \theta=\sec ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}\right)$

hence, $\theta=2 n \pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}$.

I am following Hobson's Trigonometry and it doesn't have the answer or the solution provided, neither any examples regarding inverse trigonometric functions. I got the feedback that my approach is incorrect but I cannot see how to fix it so any hints on where I am going mistaken ?

P.S. Hobson mentions that $x = \sec^{-1}(y)$ is a multi-valued function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{aligned}
9 \sec ^{4} \theta &=16 \\
\sec ^{4} \theta &=\frac{16}{9} \\
\sec \theta &=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \\
\cos \theta &=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
\theta &=n \pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}=\frac{(6 n \pm 1) \pi}{6},
\end{aligned}
$$
where $n \in \mathbb{Z}.$

Comment: But Hobson in the book mentions that the values of $\cos^{-1}(y)$ are included in $2n\pi \pm x,$ where $x = \cos y.$ So should it be $n \pi$ as you mention or $2 n \pi$ ?

Comment: Your mistake is: $\implies \sec  \theta=\frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$\\ Instead, it should be $\implies \sec  \theta=\pm \frac{2}{\sqrt 3}$

Comment: But I did take a $\pm$ right ? I mean I don't evaluate $\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}},$ and directly use $\pm \frac{\pi}{6}.$

Still I didn't get why $n \pi$ instead of $2n \pi$ ? We are only considering positives or similar reasoning ?

Comment: $\cos \theta=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Rightarrow \theta=2 n \pi \pm \frac{\pi}{6}$
$\cos \theta=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \Rightarrow \theta=2 n \pi \pm \frac{5 \pi}{6}$ Combining gives $ \theta =n\pi\pm \frac{\pi}{6}.$

Comment: $\implies \sec ^{2} \theta=\frac{4}{3} \Longrightarrow \theta=\sec ^{-1}\left(\pm \sqrt{\frac{4}{3}}\right)$

Comment: $\sec^{-1}(-\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}})=\frac{5\pi}{6}$ !

Comment: Ok I wrapped things around my head, and I see where I went wrong. Thank you for explaining all the steps! 

I also figured that when "combining" the two results, a new variable makes it much easier to grasp, as in $k$ instead of $n$ (infact, in another book I saw the two $n$ written for each value of $\cos \theta$ is written as $2m\pi \pm \alpha$ and $2 n \pi \pm \alpha$ which finally combine as $k \pi \pm \alpha.$)

Thank you again~

Comment: You are welcome.  Be aware  that $\sec^{-1}(-\sqrt{\frac{4}{3}})=\frac{5\pi}{6}\neq -\frac{\pi}{6} $ !

Answer (score 0):

$$\sec^2\theta=\dfrac43$$

$$\cos^2\theta=?$$

$$\sin^2\theta=?=\sin^2A\text{(say)}$$

Use [Prove $ \sin(A+B)\sin(A-B)=\sin^2A-\sin^2B $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175143/prove-sinab-sina-b-sin2a-sin2b) and

if $\sin y=0, y=m\pi$